# How can I use regex to match a string with several ending values including no end value?

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I'm trying to come up with with a regex statement that will match and not match the following cases:

```
CT.test                  // (1) must match
CT.test (MONT)           // (2) must match
CT.test (ABS)            // (3) must match
CT.badsf                 // (4) must not match
CT.test (WOW)            // (5) must not match
```

I've tried `CT.test( \(MONT\)| \(ABS\)|^$)`  but that only matches cases 2 and 3 and not case 1.

What is a regex statement that will match case 1, 2 and 3 and not match cases 4 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^CT\.test(?: \((?:MONT|ABS)\))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6sFOYh/1)

See the details here:

- `^` - start of string
- `CT\.test` - (note the escaped dot): a `CT.test` string
- `(?: \((?:MONT|ABS)\))?` - an optional sequence of

  - - a space
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `(?:MONT|ABS)` - `MONT` or `ABS` string
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `$` - end of string.